# Create entities from database views using eclipse and JPA

Tags: eclipse, jpa, view

Can we create entities classes from Database views using JPA Tools the way we do for database tables?

Manuj

Comment: Currently searching for an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

You use the same syntax as you would for creating entity classes for a table.  The only differences are: 1) typically views are read only, thus your entity will likely only be used as read only, and 2) Like all entities you need to have a primary key, thus your view will need to either have one column that has unique identity values, or a combination of columns that can be used as a unique identity.

Comment: what are the readymade tools to generate the entities classes?

Comment: Hi @scottGustafson, any update you have for the above comment ?

Answer (score 0):

The views are also available in the list of tables when you specify the connection and the schema. 
[image]